# Dividing array by comparing flag using array functions in php

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array in php

```
$sampleArray = array('first' => 'first', 'second' => 'second', 'third' => 'third');
```

I need to splitting the array based on value `$check`, if the `$check` is 'second', then the array need to be split like this

```
$requiredArray = array('third'=>'third')
$nonReqArray = array('first'=>'first','second'=>'second')
```

if the `$check` is 'third' then the `$requiredArray` will be empty. Please suggest the solution to this?
Tried with this

```
$afterResult = array_filter($sampleArray, function($key) use (&$requiredArray, &$nonReqArray, &$check) { 
     
        if($key > $check){
            $requiredArray[$key] = $key;
        }else{

            $nonReqArray[$key] = $key;

        }
        return true;
    }, 
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: `$i = array_search($check, $sample); $r = array_slice($sample, 0, $i); $n = array_slice($sample, $i);`

Comment: implemented by `for` loop, need solution using array function- @Ro Achterberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually solved with `for` loops. But we can solve by `array_filter` array function. The main issue is indexing is not numerical, so comparing is not easy.

```
    $cmp = false;
    $afterResult = array_filter($sampleArray, function($key) use (&$requiredArray, &$nonReqArray, &$check, &$cmp) { 
             
                if($cmp){
                    $requiredArray[$key] = $key;
                }else{

                    $nonReqArray[$key] = $key;

                }
               if($key == $check){
                  $cmp =true;
                }
                return true;
            }, 
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You tagged in PHP 7.4 but you didn't even use the arrow function

Comment: Sorry about that, not aware of arrow function. Can you please update the answer.:-@Dharman

Comment: No, I don't find your answer that useful, but I also do not think it's not useful. I neither downvote, nor upvote, but I also see no point in trying to change it. We already have such answers and they have been linked as a duplicate. If you want to learn about arrow functions you can check out the PHP manual.